# Longest Substring with K Distinct Characters - python (Why my sol works)

Tags: algorithm, sliding-window

Given a string, find the length of the longest substring in it with no more than K distinct characters.

Example:

> Input: String="araaci", K=2
> Output: 4
> Explanation: The longest substring with no more than '2' distinct characters is "araa".
>
> Input: String="araaci", K=1
> Output: 2
> Explanation: The longest substring with no more than '1' distinct characters is "aa".
>
> Input: String="cbbebi", K=3
> Output: 5
> Explanation: The longest substrings with no more than '3' distinct characters are "cbbeb" & > "bbebi".

I got my solution passed the test cases as above examples, and I think it is pretty optimized O(n) speed and O(1) space. But when I trying to go though it again, I don't quiet sure **why it is working**...

Can anyone help me understand it? much appreciated.

```py
def longest_substring_with_k_distinct(str, k):

  seen = set()
  max_, start = 0, 0
  for end in range(len(str)):
    seen.add(str[end])
    max_ = max(end-start, max_)
    while len(seen)>k:
      if str[start] in seen:
        seen.remove(str[start])
      start+=1

    

  return max_
```

---

**Update**: the sol above is **wrong**, as it only works for the test cases in the example if we tweak the first example to 'aciara', then the code won't work. The following code would be the right sol:

```py
def longest_substring_with_k_distinct(str, k):

  # TODO: Write your code here
  if not str:
    return 0
  start, max_ = 0, 0
  seen = set()
  for end in range(len(str)):
    seen.add(str[end])
    while len(seen)>k:
      if str[start] in seen:
        seen.remove(str[start])
      start+=1
    max_ = max(max_, end-start+1)

  return max_
```

Comment: Emm.. You want to know how your own algorthm works??

Comment: Yeah, at the beginning, I don’t think my origin algo make sense to me but it passes the test cases I was given. Hence, I posted the question to see if it’s some “magic” I came up by chance. Later on, by taking a break and also try on other test cases, I finally visualized the process in my brain and it turned out that the original algo only works for the particular cases. The updated version would be the right one I think.